# Turn off autoCapitalize on ALL React Native Inputs (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

Most of my Inputs are being auto-Capitalized on iOS only. I know there's the [autoCapitalize](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autocapitalize) property that I could set to false on every input to turn it off but I'm wondering if there's a global config I can apply project-wide.

Answer (score 23):

I don't know any global config for that but simplest solution that I can think of would be creating a custom component with default `autoCapitalize` value.

**Example**

```
const CustomTextInput = (props) => (<TextInput autoCapitalize="none" ...props />)
```

Comment: `autoCapitalize="false"` is no longer the correct argument, React native now expects `autoCapitalize='none'`, otherwise it returns the error: **Invalid UITextAutocapitalizationType 'false'. should be one of: ( characters, none, sentences, words )**

Answer (score 10):

Like mentioned in the comment in one of the answer, use the following props:

`autoCapitalize="none"`

Adding this as the answer as people might miss out the info in comments.