# Is there a way to set a font globally in React Native?

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to create a custom font that applies to every `Text` component in the whole application.

Is there is a way to set a font globally in React Native?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off autoCapitalize on ALL React Native Inputs (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069888/turn-off-autocapitalize-on-all-react-native-inputs-ios)

Comment: one way to use `styled component`. Define you wrapper with cust font for `Text` import it and use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default font family in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255645/how-to-set-default-font-family-in-react-native)

Answer (score 12):

One way is to create a wrapper for RN `Text` say MyTextCustomFont:

```
const MyTextCustomFont = (props) => {
   return (
        <Text style={{fontFamily:'myFont'}} {...props} >{props.children}</Text>
   )
}
```

import this `MyTextCustomFont` and use anywhere.

Another way is to define a style object and use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 5):

To do this we have to implement a method in which we will override `Text` component creation in React Native. In this we will set default font family or size or any attribute we want to set by default.

```
// typography.js

import React from 'react'
import { Text, Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export const typography = () => {
  const oldTextRender = Text.render
  Text.render = function(...args) {
    const origin = oldTextRender.call(this, ...args)
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
      style: [styles.defaultText, origin.props.style],
    })
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  defaultText: {
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans-Regular',//Default font family
  }
});
```

Then in index.js you have to do this:

```
import { typography } from './src/utils/typography'

typography()
```

Detailed answer here:
https://ospfolio.com/two-way-to-change-default-font-family-in-react-native/

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is add Custom Fonts in react native.

**1. Add Your Custom Fonts to Assets**

Add all the font files you want to an “assets/fonts” folder in the root of your react native project:

[image]

**2. Edit Package.json**

Adding rnpm to package.json providing the path to the font files:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
},
```

**3. Link assest files**

run this command in your react native project root folder

```
react-native link
```

This should add the font references in your Info.plist file for iOS and on Android copy the font files to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts.

**4. Add in stylesheet**

Add a fontFamily property with your font name:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      title: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay-Bold',
        color: '#fff',
        paddingRight: 20,
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I've made a component doing this quite easely some times ago. This is working with Expo, I don't know for vanilla react-native.

at the start of your app:

```
import { Font, Asset } from 'expo'

async initFont() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'Bariol': require('src/assets/font/Bariol_Regular.otf'),
        'Bariol Bold': require('src/assets/font/Bariol_Bold.otf'),
      })
      this.setState({ fontReady: true })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

Then, you have to create a component file like `text.js` containing this code:

```
export default function (props) {
  let font = { fontFamily: 'Bariol' }
  if (props.bold) {
    font = { fontFamily: 'Bariol Bold' }
  }

  const { bold, style, children, ...newProps } = props
  return (
    <Text {...newProps} style={[Style.text, props.style, font]}>
      {props.children}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Finally, in any of you other component / page just import MyText:

```
import Text from 'path/to/text.js'
```

use it like a normal `Text` component:

```
<Text bold>Hello World!</Text>
```

Even if this solution looks a bit more complicated than the others, it is easier to use once the setup is ok, since you just have to import Text.

Answer (score 0):

**You can override Text behaviour by adding this in any of your component using Text:**

*Edit: Add this code in your App.js or main file*

```
let oldRender = Text.render;
Text.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]
    });
}
```

*For react Native Version 0.56  or below, Add this code in your App.js or main file*

```
let oldRender = Text.prototype.render;
Text.prototype.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]
    });
};
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255645/how-to-set-default-font-family-in-react-native)
Or [create your own component, such as MyAppText.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text) 
*MyAppText would be a simple component that renders a Text component using your universal style and can pass through other props, etc.*

Comment: this doens't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I use a wrapper with default props like this :

```
const CustomText = ({ fontFam = "regular", ...props }) => {
  const typo = {
    light: "Montserrat_300Light",
    regular: "Montserrat_400Regular",
    bold: "Montserrat_600SemiBold",
  };

  return (
    <Text {...props} style={[{ fontFamily: typo[fontFam], ...props.style }]}>
      {props.children}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default CustomText;
```

By default, if "fontFam" is not indicated it will be regular font.

An example with bold typo :

```
   <CustomText fontFam="bold" style={{ marginTop: 30, color: "grey" }}>
              Some Text
   </CustomText>
```

You can replace all your `<Text/>` by `<CustomText />`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to create custom component, you could try [react-native-global-font](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-global-font). It will be apply for your all Text and TextInput

Answer (score -2):

yes

### app.js

```
import styles from './styles';
{...}
 <Text style={styles.text}>hello World </Text>
{...}
```

### styles.js

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 text: {
    // define your font or size or whatever you want to style here
  },
```

use style on every text and all changes will affect all text components